# Scala: Preference among overloaded methods with implicits, currying and defaults

Tags: scala

The following simple piece of code fails to compile:

```
object O { 
  def apply(s:String, o:Int=5)(implicit i:String) = { 
    println("am first"); 
    s 
  }

  def apply(s:String)(o:Boolean*) = { 
    println("am second"); 
    o 
  } 
}

object Main extends App {
  implicit val myS = "foo"
  O("test")
}
```

The error being

```
error: missing arguments for method apply in object O;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
  O("test")
   ^
one error found
```

This appears to be because the compiler prefers the second `apply`. But why is this? Especially considering that the conditions for applying the first `apply` are satisfied? If I delete the second `apply` the piece of code compiles fine.

Are there any way to "guide" the compiler towards compiling this correctly? Or am I forced to create two different method names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that it is possible for the Scala compiler to be smarter.  The problem is that noone has wanted to come up with the new specification for this.  It'll be very complicated.

There are ways to get around this limitation.

#### 1. replace overloading with pattern matching within `apply` to choose one of the two functions

```
def apply(s: String, i: Option[Int] = None) = {
  i match {
    case Some(n) => // call the 1st
    case None => // call the 2nd
 }
```

}

Then:

```
apply("test", Some(5)) => ... // if we want the first
apply("test") => ... // if we want the second
```

#### 2. use overloading but with different parameter names for the two functions:

```
def apply(apple: String, o: Int = 5)(implicit i: String)
def apply(banana: String)(o: Boolean*)
```

Then:

```
apply(apple = "test") // if we want the first    
apply(banana = "test") // if we want the second
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I think that solution 1 doesn't take into account that the two methods have different return types. So to be applied the return type would have to become Any and casts would be needed where it is called?

Answer (score 0):

Let's regard this situation without implicits

```
object O {
  def apply(s: String, o: Int = 5) = {
    println("am first")
  }

  def apply(s: String) = {
    println("am second")
  }
}
```

In this situation `O("test")` will be compiled with second apply, so you can't use default parameters in this situation. Implicits changes nothing here. If you'll explicitly provide Int parameter, you cod will compile with first apply.