# On Expanded Scala Method signatures

Tags: scala, function, signature

I am nearly completely new to Scala, a few months on. I  noticed some wild signatures. I have worked through generics with contrapositive/copositive/extensions/invariance, and most of the basics. However, I continue to  find some of the method signatures a bit confusing. While I find examples and know what the signatures produce, I am still a bit at a loss as to some of the functionality. Googling my questions has left me with no answers. I do have the general idea that people like to beat the basic CS 1 stuff to death. I have even tried to find answers on the scala website. Perhaps I am phrasing things like "expanded method signature" and "defining function use in scala signature" wrong. Can anyone explain this signature?

```
futureUsing[I <: Closeable, R](resource: I)(f: I => Future[R])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext):Future[R]
```

My guess is that after the initial generics and parameter declaration with a parameter of type I, the body is defined and the final portion is any objects specific to the function or that must be looked up in an implicit scope (are they destroyed afterwards?). Can anyone layout an expanded method signature so I know what code I am using?  Is there a particular order the last two parts must be in?

**Note**

After a bunch more searching, I found a few valid responses I can throw together:

-[Scala - Currying and default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676301/scala-currying-and-default-arguments)

-[why in Scala a function type needs to be passed in separate group of arguments into a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455657/why-in-scala-a-function-type-needs-to-be-passed-in-separate-group-of-arguments-i)

There is no set ordering just that implicits must be last. Placement is about dependency which flows left to right as someone down the list in one of the above answers pointed out. Why I cannot have implicits first and everything depending on them afterwards is odd since having nothing available causes an error and things will likely depend on a given implicit.

However, I am still a bit confused. When specifying f: I => Future[R], and needing to supply the last argument, lets pretend it would be any implicit, would I need to do something more like:

```
futureUsing(resourceOfI)({stuff => doStuff(stuff)})(myImplicit)
```

Is this even correct?

Could I do:

```
futureUsing(resourceOfI)(myImplicit)({stuff => doStuff(stuff)})
```

Why? I am really trying to get at the underlying reasons rather than just a binary yes or no.

**Final Note**

I just found this answer. It appears the order cannot be changed. Please correct me if I am wrong.

[Scala: Preference among overloaded methods with implicits, currying and defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316590/scala-preference-among-overloaded-methods-with-implicits-currying-and-defaults)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anyone explain this signature?

```
futureUsing[I <: Closeable, R]
```

`futureUsing` works with two separate types (two type parameters). We don't know exactly what types they are, but we'll call one `I` (input), which is a (or derived from) `Closable`, and the other `R` (result).

```
(resourse: I)
```

The 1st curried argument to `futureUsing` is of type `I`.  We'll call it `resourse`.

```
(f: I => Future[R])
```

The 2nd curried argument, `f`, is a function that takes an argument of type `I` and returns a `Future` that will (eventually) contain something of type `R`.

```
(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
```

The 3rd curried argument, `ec`, is of type `ExecutionContext`.  This argument is implicit, meaning if it isn't supplied when `futureUsing` is invoked, the compiler will look for an `ExecutionContext` in scope that has been declared `implicit` and it will pull that in as the 3rd argument.

```
:Future[R]
```

`futureUsing` returns a `Future` that contains the result of type `R`.

---

> Is there a specific ordering to this?

Implicit parameters are required to be the last (right most) parameters.  Other than that, no, `resourse` and `f` could have been declared in either order.  When invoked, of course, the order of arguments must match the order as declared in the definition.

> Do I need ... implicits to drag in?

In the case of `ExecutionContext` let the compiler use what's available from `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext`.  Only on rare occasions would you need something different.

> ...how would Scala use the 2nd curried argument...

In the body of `futureUsing` I would expect to see `f(resourse)`.  `f` takes an argument of type `I`. `resourse` is of type `I`. `f` returns `Future[R]` and so does `futureUsing` so the line `f(resourse)` might be the last statement in the body of `futureUsing`.

Comment: So is there a specific ordering to this, I understand what they do. After the initial parameter input, do I need (body function intake)(implicits to drag in)? Can I do for instance def futureUsing[E,V](par: E)(implicit ec:ExecutionContext)(f : E => Future[V]):Future[V]=Future{..... Also, how would Scala use the 2nd curried argument (f : I => Future[R]) without having it as an implicit or specified.